# PUT-Request with cURL in PHP

Tags: php, json, curl, php-curl

Here is my code:

```
$data = array(
    "status" => "ACCEPTED"
);
$url = "http://localhost:8081/lecturer-recruitment/status/application?wstoken=07fca52bc18977eaf98bd5311fcfd5bd&applicationid=1";

$payload = json_encode($data);

$curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PUT, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload );
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));

$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
print_r ($result);
```

I try to send out a PUT-Request to my local API-Endpoint inside of a Docker Container. However in my console there is never a request send out and also no error message anywhere.

Is my request not correct or could there be anything else missing?

Edit:

So the php coding is a Moodle plugin inside its own container, while the api is in a different container.
Moodle/PHP running on Port 80
API running on Port 8081

[Overview of all Docker Containers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBMXV.jpg)

Comment: To clarify: The code here is executing on the Docker container and the API is operating within the same container? And the API is listening on port 8081? Based on the light details here, I'm inclined to believe you have a docker/linux issue rather than a PHP issue.

Comment: Where is this code executed from? Same container as the endpoint being served? Or is it in a different container? In both the cases it is hitting the container's port 8081. Can you afd more details about your setup?

Comment: I edited the information about my setup. I hope this is enough information @HPierce

Comment: To access a container from another container you should use the container name, eg `http://api_mailhog_1:8081/`.  Inside a Docker container `localhost` is *that* Docker container, not your host machine.

Comment: So I changed the address to access the container. Thanks for that information. But after clicking the button in the UI, the browser shows that the page is loading but nothing happens. Also no error messages or anything in any console.